# testers reporting they can't install my Unity beta app from test flight

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, installation, testflight, beta

I built a game using Unity 4 Pro.

When I try installing my beta from TestFlight and plugging my phone up to computer and running iOS console, i get the following:

> Aug  8 02:18:26 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone syncdefaultsd[1250] :
>   (Note ) marked "com.me.keyvalueservice" topic as "opportunistic" on
>    Aug  8 02:20:23 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   kernel[0] : AppleARMPMUCharger: limiting USB input current to
>   1400 mA (measured 1240 mA) Aug  8 02:20:23 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   kernel[0] : 082182.651382 wlan0.A[3216]
>   AppleBCMWLANConfigManager::configureRoamingProfile(): Received new
>   roaming profile 3 (was 3, flag=0x0) Aug  8 02:20:23
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone SpringBoard[54] : Killing
>   com.nextbeat.scratch-island for app installation Aug  8 02:20:23
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] : LaunchServices:
>   installing app for existing placeholder  com.nextbeat.scratch-island (Placeholder) Aug  8 02:20:23
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] : LaunchServices:
>   Creating installProgressForApplication: com.nextbeat.scratch-island (Placeholder) withPhase:1 Aug
>   8 02:20:23 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone lsd[79] : LaunchServices:
>   Updating installPhase for parent  : Parent:
>   0x0 / Fraction completed: 1.0000 / Completed: 100 of 100   to 1 Aug  8
>   02:20:24 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : 0x100794000
>   -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-6609653610584707714/1964926555360872290"
>   type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 101) Aug  8 02:20:39
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] : LaunchServices:
>   installing app for existing placeholder  com.nextbeat.scratch-island (Placeholder) Aug  8 02:20:39
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : 0x102014000
>   -[MIClientConnection _doBackgroundInstallationForPath:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/8232659983358344409/-2717640436423951659"
>   type Customer requested by itunesstored (pid 101) Aug  8 02:21:23
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone ubd[1258] : iCloud Documents through
>   ubd is deactivated, using bird instead (May 29 2015 : 17:29:51). Aug 
>   8 02:21:36 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone locationd[61] : Gesture
>   EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0 Aug  8 02:21:44
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : 0x100794000
>   -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing  Aug  8 02:21:45 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   misagent[1188] : attempt to install invalid profile: 0xe8008012
>   Aug  8 02:21:45 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] :
>   0x100794000 -[MIInstallableBundle _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]:
>   Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 (Unsupported device)
>   Aug  8 02:21:45 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : 
>   SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName] Aug  8
>   02:21:52 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : entitlement
>   'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'XC:
>   com.nextbeat.scratch-island' Aug  8 02:21:52 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   installd[1122] : 0x100794000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier
>   performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)
>   Aug  8 02:21:52 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] :
>   0x100794000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification
>   stage failed Aug  8 02:21:52 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122]
>   : 0x102014000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]:
>   Installing  Aug  8 02:21:52
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone misagent[1188] : attempt to install
>   invalid profile: 0xe8008012 Aug  8 02:21:52 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   installd[1122] : 0x102014000 -[MIInstallableBundle
>   _installEmbeddedProfileInBundle:]: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012 (Unsupported device) Aug  8 02:21:52
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] :  SecTrustEvaluate 
>   [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName] Aug  8 02:21:55
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] : 0x102040000
>   __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify
>   code signature of  : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)"
>   UserInfo=0x12f3a7270 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394,
>   LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=188,
>   FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:],
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)}
>   Aug  8 02:21:55 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] :
>   ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil Aug  8
>   02:21:55 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone lsd[79] : LaunchServices:
>   installation failed for app com.nextbeat.scratch-island Aug  8
>   02:21:55 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] :
>   LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress:
>   com.nextbeat.scratch-island.Installing -  :
>   Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 100
>   called, removing progress from cache Aug  8 02:21:58
>   Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] : entitlement
>   'get-task-allow' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'XC:
>   com.nextbeat.scratch-island' Aug  8 02:21:58 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   installd[1122] : 0x102014000 -[MICodeSigningVerifier
>   performValidationWithError:]: 188: Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)
>   Aug  8 02:21:58 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone installd[1122] :
>   0x102014000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Verification
>   stage failed Aug  8 02:21:59 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone
>   itunesstored[101] : 0x1006ac000
>   __MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices_block_invoke240: Returned error Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=13 "Failed to verify
>   code signature of  : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)"
>   UserInfo=0x12f22e660 {LibMISErrorNumber=-402620394,
>   LegacyErrorString=ApplicationVerificationFailed, SourceFileLine=188,
>   FunctionName=-[MICodeSigningVerifier performValidationWithError:],
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to verify code signature of
>    : 0xe8008016
>   (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)}
>   Aug  8 02:21:59 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone itunesstored[101] :
>   ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil Aug  8
>   02:21:59 Paul-Michailidiss-iPhone lsd[79] : LaunchServices:
>   installation failed for app com.nextbeat.scratch-island

Answer (score 0):

Does the UDID of the device the tester used is in the provisioning profile? It says

> (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)

You need to register their device in the provisioning profile, unless it is Enterprise provisioning.